# accidently ran sudo mv /* /etc/ssl in my ec2 linux server

Tags: linux, bash

I just started working on a aws ec2 server and accidently ran `sudo mv /* /etc/ssl` in the shell and now all of my files etc are gone.

Before i killed the ssh connection i couldn't view any files or run any commands. Now when i try to ssh into the server it returns that the connection has been closed by port 22...
Does anyone have any ideas on how to recover the database e.g. by mounting the volume to a different server - or should i just create a new server?

BR Lukas

Comment: First thing to learn is to never kill the connection! There was a good chance you could have recovered (if the runtime linker had been moved it would have been hard but anything else would have probably taken a few seconds). Since you have "just started working" there doesn't sound as if there is anything worth putting time into recovering, so creating a new server seems a good choice.

Comment: if possible on aws, mount the disk on an other machine and move back the files

Answer (score 0):

Boot something like rescue mode or as you mentioned, another server to mount the disk to. Mount it somewhere (I'll assume `/mnt/root`). Go into `/mnt/root/etc/ssl` and move everything that doesn't belong in there back to where it goes under `/mnt/root`. If you have other partitions (I'll assume `/home` is one), then mount them too (I'll assume `/mnt/home`), and move the entire contents of `/mnt/root/home/` there (but leave the directory behind, since it's needed as a mount point). GRUB does some weirdness with exact filesystem layout, so if you can't boot after doing all that, then go back into another machine, mount all your stuff again, `chroot` in, and reinstall GRUB.